# Every monad is monoid?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Since every `Monad` is a `Monoid` on the sequencing operation.
Why doesn't `Monad` inherit `Monoid` in haskell?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'sequencing operation' here?

Comment: @Rhymoid: I'm pretty sure it's `>>`.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: A limited form of `>>`, right?

Comment: @Rhymoid: The type would have to be specialized to `Monad m => m () -> m ()`, yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a `Monad` even, this works for every `Applicative`. So yes, you could define:

```
class (Functor f, Monoid (f ())) => Applicative f where
```

But this means that you would have to provide the `Monoid` instance every time you write an `Applicative` instance. That can be quite annoying, certainly since this `Monoid` instance would not be used very often.

A better solution is to create a newtype wrapper around `f ()`, and then you can provide a `Monoid` instance for all applicative functors once and for all. There's one readily available in [the reducers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reducers/3.0.1/doc/html/Data-Semigroup-Applicative.html#t%3aTraversal).